# Excel VBA ComboBoxes to Omit Previously Selected Options

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have several ActiveX ComboBoxes with a predefined list of names:

```
"Variables!$B$1:$B$23"
```

The ComboBoxes are in cells A2 - A24.  I would like the ComboBoxes to omit previously selected options.  For example, if I were to select "John Doe" in the A2 ComboBox, when I open the A3 ComboBox "John Doe" is not listed as an option.  I was looking at the ComboBox_Change option for the ComboBox but the code eludes me. As I'm sure you can see by my feeble attempt below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim ComboValue As String

ComboValue = Worksheets("Roster").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value

For i = 2 To Worksheets("Variables").Range("C1")
    ListVariable = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B" & i)
    If (ListVariable = ComboValue) Then
    'Change other comboboxes
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```